# How To Get ALL Minimum Value Within Multidimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this code :

```
<?php

$result = array ( array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "4,3"),
                  array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "6,1"),
                  array ("split" => "3", "combo" => "2,1"),
                  array ("split" => "4", "combo" => "1,1,1,1"));

$min_x = min ( array_column( $result, 'split' ) );

print_r($min_x);
?>
```

this will give me `2` as result and I need to create some function to get the `combo value` of `2`, how to get both array value of `2` using native PHP function (is there any?) like this :

```
array ( array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "4,3"),
        array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "6,1"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the minimum number using `min` and `array_column` and finally simply use `array_filter`

```
$result = array ( array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "4,3"),
                  array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "6,1"),
                  array ("split" => "3", "combo" => "2,1"),
                  array ("split" => "4", "combo" => "1,1,1,1"));

$min = min(array_column($result,'split'));
$res = array_filter($result,function($v)use($min){ 
    return $v['split'] == $min;
});

print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [split] => 2
            [combo] => 4,3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [split] => 2
            [combo] => 6,1
        )

)
```

> Note : Working with PHP version >= 5.5.0

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr_min = array();
$arr_min["split"] = min ( array_column( $result, 'split' ) );
$arr_min["combo"] = min ( array_column( $result, 'combo' ) );
```

now you have an array of minimum value for both keys. this is just an abstract idea. You can also make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can try this,

```
<?php
$result = array ( array ("split" => "7", "combo" => "4,3"),
              array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "6,1"),
              array ("split" => "9", "combo" => "2,1"),
              array ("split" => "8", "combo" => "1,1,1,1"));
array_multisort($result);
print_r($result[0]['combo']);
?>
```

Comment: your code doesn't have duplicate value of `split`. that's why your code only give 1 value of lowest `split`, what I need is both value of lowest `split` when I have duplicate value of lowest `split`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like below:

```
<?php

$result = array ( array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "4,3"),
                  array ("split" => "2", "combo" => "6,1"),
                  array ("split" => "3", "combo" => "2,1"),
                  array ("split" => "4", "combo" => "1,1,1,1"));

$min_x = min ( array_column( $result, 'split' ) );

$new_result = array();
foreach($result as $val){
    if($val["split"] == $min_x)
    $new_result[] = $val;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_result);

?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [split] => 2
            [combo] => 4,3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [split] => 2
            [combo] => 6,1
        )

)
```

Comment: I got this error : Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in