# Get All of Value of the Shortest Array Column

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array        // count 2 values
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array        // count 2 values
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array        // count 4 values
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

)
```

and I want to get all of the value of the shortest column. in this case :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

I post about this case before here : [How To Get ALL Minimum Value Within Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168403/how-to-get-all-minimum-value-within-multidimensional-array/35168656?noredirect=1#comment58055438_35168656)

but unfortunately that case was using associative array. while in this case isn't associative array.

how to get the value from array like this?

Comment: Count size of each subarray and store it's key.

Comment: What you have tried so far. Post your attempts

Comment: My answer below is basically the same as the answer in your other question. The only difference is using `count` instead of an element of the associative array. If you understood how the earlier answer worked, how could you not be able to apply it to the modified question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the minimum length of all the sub-arrays:

```
$min_length = min(array_map('count', $array));
```

Then filter the array to get the elements that have that length:

```
$new_array = array_filter($array, function ($el) use ($min_length) {
    return count($el) == $min_length);
});
```